# Unable to position tooltip on d3.js pie chart in Angular

Tags: angular, d3.js, tooltip, pie-chart

I'm trying to integrate a working d3 code in an Angular project.

Everything's right except the tooltip position.
It should normally appears above the focused part of the pie chart but :

1. it always appears at the bottom of the graph when the tooltip is a div in the body
2. it's never displayed when I add the tooltip to the svg element

I tried

```
.style('z-index', '9999')
.style("position", "absolute")
```

and many other things but it doesn't work.

When I debug in order to see where my element is positioned in the svg (when add it to the svg), the tooltip element exists at the correct position but its dimensions are 0x0.

Same thing when I add height and width via `.attr('height', '100px').attr('width', '100px')`.

And it doesn't change anything when I modify directly the html in the browser...

You can see the complete code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tkhs5f?file=src/app/charts/pimp-chart/pimp-chart.component.ts).

I've no more idea to solve this problem. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3 v6, the API to add a tooltip has changed, so [you can change your function accordingly](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide#events):

```
onst arcs = this.arcs
const onMouseover = (event, d) => {
  const e = arcs.nodes();
  const i = e.indexOf(this);
  const pointerEvent = d3.pointer(event)
//...
}

this.arcs
  .on("mouseover", onMouseover)
```

For your tooltip, what you need is a container div that has both the SVG and the tooltip in it:

```
<div class="container">
  <svg></svg>
  <div class="tooltip"></div>
</div>
```

Set the container to be `position: relative`, and the tooltip to `position: absolute` so that its position depends on the parent, and thus **on the SVG itself**. Then you can position it with `style()`:

```
tooltip
  .style("left", `${d3.pointer(event)[0]}px`)
  .style("top", `${d3.pointer(event)[1]}px`)
```

See [d3.pointer().](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#pointer)

Comment: You're right about the container and the position, the tooltip can be moved anywhere in the svg. Thanks! But, I've a problem with your suggestion about the onMouseOver function : 1. `Property 'pointer' does not exist on type 'typeof import("<project_root>/node_modules/@types/d3/index")'`. I found the pointer.js in d3-selection/src folder but there's no exported member. 2. `Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EnterElement'` and I can make it work using d because d is contained in e[index].__data__. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Try to import it from the d3-selection module: `import { pointer } from "d3-selection";`

Comment: I already tried but it doesn't work. The import is accepted whith "d3-selection/src" but it crash at runtime...